# Unresolved top-level overloading

Tags: haskell

I need to make a Coke Vending Machine in Haskell, but I'm having some problems. I don't understand Haskell very well, so I don't know what is happening

```
main = start
       return()

start = do putStr "\nSelect a coin\n1. R$0,25\n2. R$0,50\n3. R$1,00\n"
           coin <- getChar;
           case coin of
                1 -> twentyFive
                2 -> fifty
                3 -> dispensed
                otherwise -> do putStr "Select a valid option"
                                start

twentyFive = do putStr "\nSelect a coin\n1. R$0,25\n2. R$0,50\n3. R$1,00\n"
                coin <- getChar;
                case coin of
                     1 -> fifty
                     2 -> seventyFive
                     3 -> dispensed
                     otherwise -> do putStr "Select a valid option"
                                     twentyFive

fifty = do putStr "\nSelect a coin\n1. R$0,25\n2. R$0,50\n3. R$1,00\n"
           coin <- getChar;
           case coin of
                1 -> seventyFive
                2 -> dispensed
                3 -> dispensed
                otherwise -> do putStr "Select a valid option"
                                fifty

seventyFive = do putStr "\nSelect a coin\n1. R$0,25\n2. R$0,50\n3. R$1,00\n"
                 coin <- getChar;
                 case coin of
                      1 -> dispensed
                      2 -> dispensed
                      3 -> dispensed
                      otherwise -> do putStr "Select a valid option"
                                      seventyFive

dispensed = do putStr "-- Coke Dispensed --"
               return()
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Unresolved top-level overloading
*** Binding             : seventyFive
*** Outstanding context : Num Char
```

What does this mean?

Comment: You’ve said you’re new to Haskell, so maybe you don’t know that `return()` is not necessary, and `;` at the end of `getChar` isn’t needed either.

Comment: You probably ought to give explicit type signatures to your functions, it can make errors like this clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not indented the body of `seventyFive` the same way that you've indented the bodies of your other functions.

Should be indented like this instead:

```
seventyFive = do putStr "\nSelect a coin\n1. R$0,25\n2. R$0,50\n3. R$1,00\n"
                 coin <- getChar
                 case coin of
                      1 -> dispensed
                      2 -> dispensed
                      3 -> dispensed
                      otherwise -> do putStr "Select a valid option"
                                      seventyFive
```

The error message is because Hugs thinks the first line of your function is also the last line. (You had the second line not indented as far as that part of the first line that is after the `do`.)

Btw, use GHC instead of Hugs if you can (ideally as part of the Haskell Platform) as Hugs has not been maintained for some years.

---

Not an error, but it also looks odd that you have

```
                 coin <- getChar;
```

Replace with

```
                 coin <- getChar
```

---

More errors:

```
main = start
       return()
```

should be

```
main = do start
          return()
```

or (because we don't have to have `main :: IO ()`, we can have `main :: IO anythingWeWant`) just

```
main = start
```

And finally, you are calling `getChar`, which will give you a `Char`, but pattern matching as if it gives you a number. You need to enclose the digit in single quotes (e.g. `'1'` instead of `1`).

Comment: That was a problem when I paste the code here, the code is indented correctly, but the error still occurs

Comment: If you are using tabs in your source code, replace them with spaces.

Comment: @J0rge: Please look at last two lines of `seventyFive`. There’s still a mistake with indentation there.

Comment: Well, I'm new here too, so I think pasted the code wrong, but I idented it correctly.

And I put the ; there because otherwise I get this error:
    Last generator in do {...} must be an expression